# ssh -F configfile and ProxyCommand

Tags: ssh

I would like to use a ssh_config file instead of the traditional ~/.ssh/config. I have a simple configuration for accessing hosts through a bastion host (on port 23 for example).

ssh_config :

```
host bastion
    hostname bastion.mydomain.com
    port 23

host *.server
    proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion
```

`ssh -F ssh_config test.server` is not working and throw me "ssh: Could not resolve hostname bastion: Name or service not known".

But, if put this config in ~/.ssh/config, then `ssh test.server` works.

As I understand it, the proxycommand is unable to use the config file given in the command line. 
If I want my command line config file to work, I need to put

```
    proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion.mydomain.com -p 23
```

but this seems to violate a simple DRY principle (the port and the domain are repeated). The config file I'm willing to build is much much longer and complex.

Is there a good way to achieve what I want, i.e. a simple, non-repeating, config file usable in command line for which proxycommand works ?

Comment: specifying `proxycommand -F ssh_config` does work. But then I need to repeat this everywhere in the config_file. And changing the name of the file is catastrophic. So my question about a better way to achieve that should still stand.

Comment: Could you explain to us why you're trying to avoid using the normal `~/.ssh/config` file?  That is obviously the easiest solution. Otherwise, specifying `-F path/to/config` anywhere you invoke ssh is probably your best bet.

Comment: @larsks I would like to put this config file in a git repo and have an ansible configuration that get along with. Thanks for the quick, but depressing, answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half of an answer:
Rather than using the config file recursively, try not relying on the config at all for the proxy command.

```bash
host *.server
    proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion.mydomain.com -p 23
```

This allows it to be portable, but doesn't solve your other issue of having to do this on every line, and makes changing the bastion host address a difficult process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your custom config to the `ProxyCommand`, too.

```bash
proxycommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion -F [your custom ssh config]
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't do this at the time you asked the question, but as of [OpenSSH v7.3](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3) in 2016, you can [`Include` your extra Git-tracked *ssh_config* file](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/openssh-client/ssh_config.5.en.html#Include) in your main *~/.ssh/config*:

```bash
Include path/to/other/ssh_config
```